# how to redirect page on not found exception error in cakephp 3

Tags: php, error-handling, exception, cakephp-3.0

i want to redirect my application to home page on incorrect request or not found exception

in app.php file `'debug' => false,` i have done it

and in app controller i have used this code --

```
public function afterFilter(Event $event) {
         var_dump($this->response->statusCode());die;
        if ($this->response->statusCode() != '200')
        {
            return $this->redirect("/home");
        }
      }
```

but in this case on correct request it`s print 200 but on incorrect request it`s doesn`t print 404 or 400 etc.on incorrect request it`s show not found error please see attached image[image]

Comment: Your controller action is perhaps not catching the `RecordNotFound` exception that might be thrown for a non-existent record, and as a result afterFilter is never being run?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to redirect. CakePHP will automatically handle the `404 - Not Found` exceptions.

Just make sure that you have `error404.ctp` in `src\Template\Error` and `error.ctp` in `src\Template\Layout`.
You can then modify `error404.ctp` to show your Error page for 'Not found' exceptions.

If `error404.ctp` does not work, try the same with `error400.ctp` in `src\Template\Error`. It should work.

Comment: i didn`t found error404.ctp file in src\Template\Error now what we have to do

Comment: and i want to redirect don`t want to show any error page there is any idea for this ??

Answer (score 0):

```
   $ctp_file =  __FUNCTION__;
   //$view = '/yourController/yourCtpFile/'.$ctp_file;
   $view = '/yourController/home/'.$ctp_file;
   $this->render($view);
```

OR

```
   $view = '/yourController/home/';
   $this->render($view);
```